# Steps to create Android Workspace with auto build JNI C++ ".so"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have gone through [this opencv Android samples link](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/face-detection). In this link all the projects has a JNI C++ code which builds the ".so" file automatically and build the project. I need to create a sample project like the above examples, in which the C++ code builds automatically.

I have gone through few [tutorials like this](http://taylorpeer.com/hello-world-cpp-android-ndk/), which has steps to build JNI using command line but there is no steps to build it automatically/using eclipse project.

Can any one list out the steps to create a project in eclipse that builds JNI C++ files automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you can read the article [Getting Started with JNI on Android, Windows and Mac](http://www.codepool.biz/tech-frontier/android/getting-started-with-jni-on-android-windows-and-mac.html). You just need to right-click on your project and select Add Native Support. Then the IDE will automatically build the .so when you save all changes.